# Get value of dynamic created select related to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got stuck with targeting the correct element and I hope you can help me.

So:
I have fields generated by **PHP** script:

```html
<fieldset>

  <div class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>


</fieldset>
```

And I need to initialize an auto complete plugin over each of textfield on focus, based on what is selected inside the select in the row, where is the textbox.

Because of templates of project, where I don't have access, I cannot edit the ID or classes of rows (like numbering the rows), so even this is a simplified solution, it is all like what I am working with.

So, once again, what I need to achieve:

```js
    $(input).focus(function(){
Ask_what_is_in_select_at_the_same_row()
Store_value_of_Selected_Option_to_Variable()

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way:

```
$('div.row :text').focus(function(){
    // get the value of the select which is the sibling of focussed text input.
    var optVal = $(this).siblings('select').find('option:selected').val();
    // now you can use it.
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xpx380w3/)

Comment: You should be able to get the value of the dropdown with just `$(this).siblings('select').val()`.

Comment: @flowstoneknight absolutely that can also be done. even you can also use `.prev()` too.

Comment: I just mean you don't need the `.find('option:selected')` part, since the `<select>` will have the value of whichever `<option>` is selected.

Comment: @flowstoneknight that is much more you can say for readability like what is the element what we are targeting. although that also works what you posted. thanks.